# jParallax trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey everyone! I have a problem with this plugin. I have no idea what is wrong here... All I did was the same as in the examples.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parallax"> 
    <div style="width: 830px; height: 280px;">  
        <img style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:350px;" alt="" src="images/smile1.png"/>  
    </div>  
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 250px;">  
        <img style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:0px;" alt="" src="images/smile1.png"/>  
    </div>  
    <div style="width: 1000px; height: 260px;">  
        <img style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:150px;" alt="" src="images/smile1.png"/>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parallax { 
    background:#ccc;  
    position:absolute;  
    overflow:hidden; 
    width:700px;  
    height:300px;  
}
```

**JS**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
       jQuery('#parallax').jparallax({}); 
   }); 
   </script>
```

and nothing happened... pictures are standing without any movements... any ideas?

Comment: oh, i just figured it out. i solved my problem using another version of jquery. it seems strange but 1.5.1 is not okey with that plugin, as well as all versions higher than 1.3.2

Comment: Go ahead and post your solution as an answer, and then click the check mark beside it, so people will know this question has been answered :)

Comment: i'm sorry i found solution accidentally. i just changed one number in the jquery version and wow!

Comment: Please post your solution as new answer and accept it so the question will be marked solved.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately his site has not been updated for a while, you can get version 1.0 from his GitHub repo which works with jQuery v1.7 (latest version at the time of writing).

https://github.com/stephband/jparallax[jParallax github](https://github.com/stephband/jparallax)